# JOptionPange: Can't print String.format table even with monospaced font

Tags: java, string, swing, string-formatting, joptionpane

I'm trying to display a table inside `JOptionPane`. However the column indents are off. I tried to change the font to monospaced, but it didn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"tom","john", "vincent", "dan"};
        String[] colors = {"red", "orange", "green", "blue"};
        String[] pets = {"dog", "crocodile", "monkey", "parrot"};
        int[] ages = {23, 5454, 1, 6565, 87};

        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            s += String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20d%n",
                names[i], colors[i], pets[i], ages[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(s);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

the console output looks like this:

[image]

The first window looks like this (as can be seen the columns are off):

[image]

The second window looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the table be printed just the way it's printed in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JTextArea`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] names = {"tom","john", "vincent", "dan"};
        String[] colors = {"red", "orange", "green", "blue"};
        String[] pets = {"dog", "crocodile", "monkey", "parrot"};
        int[] ages = {23, 5454, 1, 6565, 87};

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                s.append("\n");

            s.append(String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20d", names[i], colors[i], pets[i], ages[i]));
        }

        JTextArea label = new JTextArea(s.toString());
        label.setOpaque( false );
        label.setEditable( false );
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12));

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I present two possibilities.

1. The `message` parameter in the overloaded `showMessageDialog` methods of class `JOptionPane` is an `Object`. Hence it can be **anything** you want. So I used `javax.swing.JTable`.
2. You tried `JLabel` but `JLabel` does not honor newline characters in its text, hence the text appears in one, long line. However, the text of a `JLabel` can contain HTML tags. So my second implementation uses `JLabel` with a HTML table.

Here is the code. (Explanations after it.)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"tom", "john", "vincent", "dan"};
        String[] colors = {"red", "orange", "green", "blue"};
        String[] pets = {"dog", "crocodile", "monkey", "parrot"};
        int[] ages = {23, 5454, 1, 6565, 87};
        String s = "<html><table>";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            s += String.format("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%d</td></tr>",
                               names[i],
                               colors[i],
                               pets[i],
                               ages[i]);
        }
        String[][] data = new String[][]{{"tom", "red", "dog", "23"},
                                         {"john", "orange", "crocodile", "5454"},
                                         {"vincent", "green", "monkey", "1"},
                                         {"dan", "blue", "parrot", "6565"}};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, new String[]{"", "", "", ""});
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 18));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label, "ERROR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

- I used dummy column headers for the `JTable` since the headers are not displayed if the `JTable` is not wrapped in a `JScrollPane`. You can't use null because that causes a `NullPointerException`.
- By default, `JTable` displays grid lines, hence the call to method `setShowGrid(false)` because I understand that you don't want grid lines.
- The text of the `JLabel` is a HTML table. Note that the HTML string does not have to be valid. (Notice that it does not contain tags `<body>` or `<head>` nor even a closing `</html>`).

Here is the first `JOptionPane`, with `JTable`.

[image: JTable in JOptionPane]

Here is the second `JOptionPane`, with `JLabel` and HTML text.

[image: JLabel with HTML in JOptionPane]

Answer (score 1):

I would output the text as HTML at this point. You only need to add one line to your code to get the result you want.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"tom","john", "vincent", "dan"};
        String[] colors = {"red", "orange", "green", "blue"};
        String[] pets = {"dog", "crocodile", "monkey", "parrot"};
        int[] ages = {23, 5454, 1, 6565, 87};

        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            s += String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20d%n",
                names[i], colors[i], pets[i], ages[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(s);

        s = "<html><pre>" + s.replace(System.lineSeparator(), "<br/>") + "</html>";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

Maybe that's a viable solution.